# Loop through Textboxes in asp.net and fill with array of string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is my code

```
  Dim str As String = "str1,str2"
    Dim array() As String = str.Split(",")
    Dim MyListOfTextBoxes() As TextBox = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3}
    For index = 0 To array.Count - 1
        For i = 0 To MyListOfTextBoxes.Length - 1
            MyListOfTextBoxes(i).Text = array(index)
        Next
    Next
```

I have 5 textboxes. I want to fill just textbox1 and textbox2 with array value. because no I have to word. but when I run the code `"str1"` repetition  on `textbox1`,`textbox2` and `textbox3`.

Comment: You really shouldn't hardcode in your TextBox names.  What happens when the form changes?  And you add/delete a TextBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need one loop to do it

```
  Dim str As String = "str1,str2"
    Dim array() As String = str.Split(",")
    Dim MyListOfTextBoxes() As TextBox = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3}
    For index = 0 To array.Count - 1
       if(MyListOfTextBoxes.Length>index)
       MyListOfTextBoxes(index).Text = array(index)
    Next
```

Comment: thanks for your response.`MyListOfTextBoxes(index)` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your code runs through elements 0, 1 and 2, which correspond to TextBox1, TextBox2, and TextBox3. If you only want to populate TextBox1 and TextBox2 then remove TextBox3 from the array.

You also have a loop within another loop - I don't see why you're doing that.

Comment: but i need textbox3 because my str maybe have 3 word and textbox mustbe fill.with `For index = 0 To array.Count - 1
` i put the array value in textboxes.